# Get latest row on selecting multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    enc.id, enc.cus_id, enc.createdon, enc.status, enc.segment, enc_task.orderid, 
    enc_task.taskid, enc.currentstep, enc.groupid, enc.fdprotocol, 
    enc_task.linkfile, cus.fname, cus.lname, login.first_name, login.last_name, 
    login.username, login.user_code, login.id as assigned_id, fp.protocol, 
    init.typename, table4.allowtotal 
FROM 
    mob_encounters enc 
    JOIN mob_encounters_task enc_task ON enc_task.encounterid=enc.id
    JOIN mob_customer cus ON cus.id=enc_task.cus_id
    JOIN mob_login login ON login.id=enc.createdby
    LEFT JOIN mob_protocol_type fp ON fp.id=enc.fdprotocol
    LEFT JOIN initiation_type init ON init.id=enc.groupid
    LEFT JOIN mob_table4 table4 ON table4.encid=enc.id

GROUP BY 
    enc.id
```

The query is working, except I need it to return the latest row of `enc_task.encounterid` when doing this match: `enc_task.encounterid = enc.id`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subquery might do what you're looking for:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
                enc.id, enc.cus_id, enc.createdon, enc.status, enc.segment, enc_task.orderid, enc_task.taskid,
                enc.currentstep, enc.groupid, enc.fdprotocol, enc_task.linkfile, cus.fname, 
                cus.lname, login.first_name, login.last_name, login.username, login.user_code,
                login.id as assigned_id, fp.protocol, init.typename, table4.allowtotal 
            FROM 
                mob_encounters enc 
            JOIN 
                (select encounterid, orderid, taskid, linkfile from mob_encounters_task order by [FIELD THAT DESIGNATES LATEST VALUE] desc) AS enc_task ON enc_task.encounterid=enc.id
            JOIN 
                mob_customer cus ON cus.id=enc_task.cus_id
            JOIN 
                mob_login login ON login.id=enc.createdby
            LEFT JOIN 
                mob_protocol_type fp ON fp.id=enc.fdprotocol
            LEFT JOIN 
                initiation_type init ON init.id=enc.groupid
            LEFT JOIN 
                mob_table4 table4 ON table4.encid=enc.id
            GROUP BY 
                enc.id
```

Comment: Thanks! It is what i wanted to do!

Comment: I just noticed that some fields are not returned like: orderid, taskid. But the others are, any idea why?

Comment: Check that subquery itself; do you have values in the rows that are returned?  My first thought is it's a data issue, or possibly I have the wrong field names.